# Getting a 500 internal server error when attempting to get the featured playlists using Express Fetch API

Tags: node.js, express, fetch-api, spotify

I am not sure why I am getting a 500 internal server error when I am attempting to get the featured playlists using Express Fetch API. I understand that this may have to do with spotify token call. I am not sure where it is going wrong.

I tried to get the featured playlist using spotify API using the client credentials authorization method. Instead of the playlist, I am getting 500 internal server error. This is my code

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const PORT = 3001;

const app = express();

const corsOptions = {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    credentials: true,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const fetch = import("node-fetch").then((module) => module.default);

const CLIENT_ID = "******";
const CLIENT_SECRET = "*******";

const SPOTIFY_TOKEN_URL = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";
const SPOTIFY_PLAYLISTS_URL = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/featured-playlists";

async function getSpotifyToken() {
    const response = await fetch(SPOTIFY_TOKEN_URL, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Basic " + Buffer.from(CLIENT_ID + ":" + CLIENT_SECRET).toString("base64"),
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        body: "grant_type=client_credentials",
        json: true,
    });

    if (response.ok) {
        const jsonResponse = await response.json();
        console.log(jsonResponse);
    } else {
        console.log(response.statusText);
        throw new Error(
            `Request failed! Status code: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`
        );
    }
}

async function getPlaylistInfo(accessToken) {
    const endpoint = SPOTIFY_PLAYLISTS_URL;

    const options = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer" + accessToken,
        },
    };

    try {
        const response = await fetch(endpoint, options);
        console.log("Spotify API Response Status:", response.status);
        console.log("Spotify API Response Headers:", response.headers.raw());

        if (response.ok) {
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log("Spotify API Data:", data);
            return data;
        } else {
            console.error("Error fetching playlist from Spotify:", response.status, await response.text() );
            throw new Error("Error fetching playlist from Spotify");
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during Spotify API request:", error.message);
        throw error;
    }
}

app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const tokenData = await getSpotifyToken();

        if (tokenData.access_token) {
            req.spotifyAccessToken = tokenData.access_token;
            next();
        } else {
            console.error("Error obtaining Spotify access token:", tokenData);
            res.status(tokenResponse.status).json({
                error: "Error obtaining Spotify access token"
            });
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error obtaining Spotify access token:", error.message);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: "Error obtaining Spotify access token",
            details: error.message,
        });
    }
});

app.get("/api/featuredplaylists", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const playlistInfo = await getPlaylistInfo(req.spotifyAccessToken);
        res.json(playlistInfo);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: "Error fetching playlist from Spotify",
            details: error.message,
        });
    }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: What do you see in logs? If you see 500 error in browser you're likely responding with `details: error.message,` so what is the error.message?

Comment: @Molda: I am not sure if I am answering your question correctly. But, I am not seeing anything else except the following {"error":"Error obtaining Spotify access token"} on the Port 3001. In the console, I am seeing only 'GET http://localhost:3001/500 Internal Server Error).

In the front end, I am seeing the following error: Error fetching playlists from Spotify: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs to be fixed in a couple of places.

#1 No space between Bearer and token

Before

```
Authorization: "Bearer" + accessToken,
```

After

```
Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
```

#2 No return a response in getSpotifyToken()

Before

```
    if (response.ok) {
        const jsonResponse = await response.json();
        console.log(jsonResponse);
    }
```

After

```
    if (response.ok) {
        const jsonResponse = await response.json();
        console.log(jsonResponse);
        return jsonResponse;
    }
```

#3 Credential put in body of POST call instead of base64

Before

```
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Basic " + Buffer.from(CLIENT_ID + ":" + CLIENT_SECRET).toString("base64"),
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        body: "grant_type=client_credentials",
```

After

```
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        body: 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=' + CLIENT_ID + '&client_secret=' + CLIENT_SECRET,
```

#4 Using module type

In package.json

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.2"
  }
}
```

So full code in here
Save as `get-song.js`

```js
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const PORT = 3001;
const app = express();

const corsOptions = {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    credentials: true,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
const CLIENT_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

const SPOTIFY_TOKEN_URL = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";
const SPOTIFY_PLAYLISTS_URL = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/featured-playlists";

async function getSpotifyToken() {
    const response = await fetch(SPOTIFY_TOKEN_URL, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        body: 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=' + CLIENT_ID + '&client_secret=' + CLIENT_SECRET,
        json: true,
    });

    if (response.ok) {
        const jsonResponse = await response.json();
        console.log(jsonResponse);
        return jsonResponse;
    } else {
        console.log(response.statusText);
        throw new Error(
            `Request failed! Status code: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`
        );
    }
}

async function getPlaylistInfo(accessToken) {
    const endpoint = SPOTIFY_PLAYLISTS_URL;

    const options = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
        },
    };

    try {
        const response = await fetch(endpoint, options);
        console.log("Spotify API Response Status:", response.status);
        console.log("Spotify API Response Headers:", response.headers.raw());

        if (response.ok) {
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log("Spotify API Data:", JSON.stringify(data));
            return data;
        } else {
            console.error("Error fetching playlist from Spotify:", response.status, await response.text());
            throw new Error("Error fetching playlist from Spotify");
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during Spotify API request:", error.message);
        throw error;
    }
}

app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const tokenData = await getSpotifyToken();

        if (tokenData.access_token) {
            req.spotifyAccessToken = tokenData.access_token;
            next();
        } else {
            console.error("Error obtaining Spotify access token:", tokenData);
            res.status(tokenResponse.status).json({
                error: "Error obtaining Spotify access token"
            });
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error obtaining Spotify access token:", error.message);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: "Error obtaining Spotify access token",
            details: error.message,
        });
    }
});

app.get("/api/featuredplaylists", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const playlistInfo = await getPlaylistInfo(req.spotifyAccessToken);
        res.json(playlistInfo);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: "Error fetching playlist from Spotify",
            details: error.message,
        });
    }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`));
```

Install dependencies

```
npm install
```

Run it

```
node get-song.js
```

Access it

```
http://localhost:3001/api/featuredplaylists
```

Result
[image]

Terminal Log
[image]